# Zero tensor product over non-commutative rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

It is known that if $R$ is a commutative ring and $M\otimes_R N=0$ for two finitely generated $R$-modules $M$ and $N$, then $Ann(M)+Ann(N)=R$, where $Ann()$ stands for the annihilator. The proof that I know uses an argument involving determinants of matrices with entries in $R$ and is therefore dependent to the commutativity of $R$.

I want to know what happens if I drop the commutativity hypothesis? Clearly, the annihilators $Ann(M)$ and $Ann(N)$ are two-sided ideals and one may still form the sum $Ann(M)+Ann(N)$. Is it true that
$Ann(M)+Ann(N)=R$ in this case?

Comment: In the noncommutative case, $M$ needs to be a right $R$-module and $N$ a left $R$-module for $M \otimes_{R} N$ to make sense.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg The annihilator of an _element_ of a right or left $R$-module is a right or left ideal of $R$. But the annihilator of the entire module is a two-sided ideal.

Comment: (I deleted my wrong comment)

Comment: Let me write down a proof in the commutative case, let's see if we can adapt it somehow (or use it to find a counterexample, which is more my feeling right now). Assume $Ann(M)+Ann(N)$ is proper, then it lies in some maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. We have $M/\mathfrak{m}M \otimes_{R/\mathfrak{m}} N/\mathfrak{m}N=0$, so linear algebra tells us that one of the factors is zero, say $M/\mathfrak{m}M=0$. Then Nakayama implies $aM=0$ for some $a  \in R$ with $a \equiv 1 \bmod \mathfrak{m}$. But then $a \in \mathrm{Ann}(M) \subseteq \mathfrak{m}$, a contradiction.

Comment: When adapting this, it seems to me that we should first handle the case of a [simple ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_ring) $R$. We need to prove that $M \otimes_R N = 0 \implies M = 0 \vee N = 0$ for these (because the conclusion is equivalent to $Ann(M)+Ann(N)=R$).  But is this true at all?

Comment: Surely that is true when $R$ is a division ring (then every module is free), and probably(?) then also when $R$ is a finite product of matrix rings over division rings. The basic example of a simple ring that does not have this form is the Weyl algebra $k\langle x,y : xy-yx=1 \rangle$. I have found some literature about their modules, and I suggest to look there first.

Comment: Martin! It seems that $R$ having a unity is indispensable. Even it has been used in the statement you gave above. Plus, could you please give the name of the book, or paper you found?

Comment: Rings have a unit by default, this is why you don't need to mention it.

Comment: I realized that I can state my initial problem as follows: Let $R$ be a (not necessarily commutative) ring, and $M$ and $N$ be (nonzero) right and left finitely generated $R$-modules,  respectively. If $M\otimes_R N=0$, is it true that the annihilator of $M$ (or N) is nonzero? Clearly in the commutative case, this follows from what I stated in the original question above.